# Which characters get exp when killing monsters?

Tags: genshin-impact

I have been primarily increasing the level of my characters using the various [writs and advice items](https://genshin-impact.fandom.com/wiki/Category:Character_EXP_Material).

However I have had a character level up through fighting monsters.

I don't understand who gets what exp points when they are awarded. Is it just the character who kills the monster or the whole party?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Based on my own experience and testing, every member in your party will gain the Character EXP when defeating monsters.

I tested this by keeping track of my party member’s experience points and then fighting monsters in the over-world. After defeating a few enemies and re-checking my character, all four members of the party’s experience points had increased