# How is XP shared between party members?

Tags: genshin-impact

When you gain XP in Genshin Impact, is the XP shared between party members, or is it only the 'active' party member that gets the benefit?

Does that change if the current party/active party member is max level?

Comment: Related, probably dup: [Which characters get exp when killing monsters?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/376201/124566)

Comment: It is. I will keep this up for the added detail that having a character that is max level in the party is not optimal.

Comment: worth noticing that while the exp you get from sources outside the three tier of exp scrolls will become mostly irrelevant very soon, the same logic is applied to friendship points too. So, any consideration you made for XP you can apply to friendship.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Character XP is given to **each member of your party**, regardless of participation. Dead party members will still receive Character XP. Characters not in your active party will **not receive Character XP**. Character XP not from materials is gained from quests, defeating enemies, and claiming Boss rewards. So all shared XP only goes equaly to active party members even if they are max level. If you want to level up a character put them into your party.

Comment: Yeah the biggest thing I wanted to know was that even if they were max level, they pulled XP. So keeping someone at their max level in the party is not optimal.

Comment: It's the same with friendship xp, that's shared among all current party members as well.

Comment: @Fredy31 Notice that in many cases the exp and/or friendship points are given out when you claim the rewards, not when completing the challenge. It is perfectly possible to complete a Ley Line challenge and then swap your entire party *before* claiming the reward from the blossom. Obviously does not work for any challenge that limits your ability to change party (like any weekly boss excluding the wolf) but you can still use the same trick with open world bosses too.